# Skip property in iteration while copying array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I am building a new array from the one returned to me out of my database. My original array consists of many objects and several objects can be the same like this one:

```
object(stdClass)[26]
  public 'id' => string '6' (length=1)
  public 'title' => string 'Something' (length=41)
  public 'excerpt' => string '<p>Something</p>' (length=104)
  public 'content' => string '<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>' (length=18)
  public 'location' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'author' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'date' => string '2015-09-28' (length=10)
  public 'publish' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'top' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'post_id' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'news_image_path' => string '14545819551_gallery.jpg' (length=23)
  public 'news_main_image' => string '0' (length=1)
```

The only difference in this same objects is in "news_image_path" property and in "news_main_image" property which is either "0", "1" or NULL. According to that "news_main_image" I want to merge that same objects and I want that only the one with `'news_main_image' => string '1'` survives the process if there is neither the property of 'news_image_path' should be NULL or if there is `'news_main_image' => string '0'` property 'news_image_path' should also be null.

**In short:**

if `'news_main_image' => string '1'` then `'news_image_path' => string '14545819576_main.jpg'`

if `'news_main_image' => string '0'` then `'news_image_path' => NULL`

if `'news_main_image' => NULL` then `'news_image_path' => NULL`

But every other property should stay the same!

My code so far but it is overriding itself and if there was `news_image_path` set in previous iteration it copies NULL over it:

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value)
{   
   if ($value->news_main_image == '1')
   {
       $tmp[$value->id] = $value;
       $tmp[$value->id]->news_image_path = $value->news_image_path;
   }
   elseif ($value->news_main_image == '0')
   {
       // DO SOMETHING HERE that will copy to the new array but it wont copy over the existing $tmp[$value->id]->news_image_path
       $tmp[$value->id] = $value;
       $tmp[$value->id]->news_image_path = NULL;
   }
   else
   {
      $tmp[$value->id] = $value;
   }

}
$result = $tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

I slightly improved your code and tried it, and work fine.

```
    foreach ($itemArray as $item)
    {
       $tmp[$item->id] = $item;

       if ($item->news_main_image == '0'){
           $tmp[$item->id]->news_image_path = NULL;
       }

    }
    $result = $tmp;
```

But it should does exactly the samy as yours...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an array of objects that looks like this if I understood you :

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#22 (2) {
    //....
    ["news_image_path"]=>
    string(23) "14545819551_gallery.jpg"
    ["news_main_image"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#23 (2) {
    //...
    ["news_image_path"]=>
    string(23) "14545819552_gallery.jpg"
    ["news_main_image"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

you can try this code below

```
 //$o is the array of objects you have
 //$res will be your result array of objects
 $res = array(); 
 foreach ( $o as $a ){
    //$tmp will be your new object
    $tmp = $a; 
    if (! $a->news_main_image ){
        $tmp->news_image_path = null; 
    }
    $res[] = $tmp; 
 }
```

and your output will look like this

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#22 (2) {
    ["news_image_path"]=>
    string(23) "14545819551_gallery.jpg"
    ["news_main_image"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#23 (2) {
    ["news_image_path"]=>
    NULL
    ["news_main_image"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Though I hate to use two `foreach` statements here is the solution. If someone can write this better please tell me:

```
        foreach ($result as $key => $value)
        {   
            if ($value->news_main_image == '1')
            {
                $news_image_path[$value->id] = $value->news_image_path;
            }
            else
            {
                $value->news_image_path = NULL;
            }

            $tmp[$value->id] = $value;
        }

        foreach ($news_image_path as $key => $value)
        {
            $tmp[$key]->news_image_path = $value;
        }

        $result = $tmp;
```